# Django filter returning empty query set even though there is a match to data

Tags: django, django-models, django-filter

I have a Django site, and am looking to filter my model for a specific field. The field, CreatedDate is a datetime field, and it is returning none, even though I am certain that the data I specify is in the query set.

I have tried casting the user entered date to a datetime object, parsing through the query set and adding each models CreatedDate into a list, and then checking if the user entered date is in the list, which it is( this is how I know the data is there

**views.py**

```py
if createdDate[0] == '>':
    createdDate = createdDate[1:]
    cd = datetime.strptime(createdDate, '%Y-%m-%d')
    try: 
        query_results = query_results.filter(CreatedDate__gte=cd)
    except Exception as e:
        print2(e)
elif createdDate[0] == '<':
    createdDate = createdDate[1:]
    cd = datetime.strptime(createdDate, '%Y-%m-%d')
    try: 
        query_results = query_results.filter(CreatedDate__lte=cd)
    except Exception as e:
        print2(e)
else:
    cd = datetime.strptime(createdDate, '%Y-%m-%d')
    try:
        print2(createdDate)
        print2(query_results)
        query_results = query_results.filter(CreatedDate__icontains=cd)
    except Exception as e:
        print2(e)
```

**models.py**

```
CreatedDate = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
```

```sql
Database - Column CreatedDate sample
2019-08-09 10:33:06.700
2019-08-09 10:33:06.700
2019-08-09 10:33:06.700
2019-09-27 00:00:00.000
2019-09-27 00:00:00.000
2019-09-27 00:00:00.000
```

I have no Idea why the filter is returning an empty query set, even though the dates that I enter are clearly in the database. If I am missing anything please let me know, otherwise please let me know if you have a solution

Comment: query_results is a query set consisting of all the models, gotten through Model.objects.all()

Comment: Are you sure you have something in `query_results` in the first place? How do the values of your filter look like? I mean, the datetime you're trying to filter for.

Comment: Yes Within the __str__ method of this Model, I have it displaying CreatedDate, and it shows all of the items in the table, up to the point where Django truncates them. I can visibly see the dates that I am entering on the site